# "Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + filName doesnt force pdf files to show

Tags: javascript, c#, html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I want when the link being clicked first to show pdf files in new tab as preview then allow users to download the file.

so i looked for the answer and they mostly say that i should include these two headers

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + filName + "\"");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
```

but it doesnt work and pdf files just start to download. here is my code:

**C# :**

```
public FileContentResult GetVisaAproveFile(Guid id)
    {
        var request = visaRequestRepository.GetById(id);
        AttachedFile ApprovedAttachedFile = request.AttachedFiles.FirstOrDefault(f => f.DocType == DocType.ApprovedDocument);
        byte[] filByte = ApprovedAttachedFile?.FileContent ?? new byte [0];
        string filName = ApprovedAttachedFile?.AttachFileSource ?? "بدون عنوان";
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + filName + "\"");
        return File(filByte, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filName));
    }
```

**JavaScript :**

```
$scope.onShowCertificate = function (e) {
        debugger;
        var id = e.key.VisaReqId;

        var url = $window.location.origin + "/UploadFile/GetVisaAproveFile/?id=" + id;
        $window.open(url, '_blank');

    };
```

**HTML :**

```
<div data-options="dxTemplate:{ name:'Certificate' }">
                            <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt ajaxresub'
                               ng-if="item.value == 8"
                               style='color: blue;cursor: pointer !important;'
                               ng-click="onShowCertificate(item)"></i>
 </div>
```

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my example :

use **FileResult**  in your action.
**DO NOT** reutrn File().

return **FileStreamResult()**.

```
[HttpGet]
public FileResult GetVisaAproveFile(string id)
{
  //skip content
  //Put your PDF in MemoryStream 
  MemoryStream msResult = ReadPDF();

  var fileResult = new FileStreamResult(msResult, "application/pdf");
  Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("inline; filename={0}.pdf", id));

  return fileResult;
}
```

Comment: looks like you got the answer there , thanks for your help :).

Comment: @TaiwanHotDog I tried but the filename still not correctly set, is there any other way?